# ideas to create a software where shows views of cubes?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, drawing

I'm planning to draw these shapes in WPF. It's for an educational software.

What idea's do you have in how to implement these cubes and views?

I was planning at the beginning starting using canvas and draw, but I guess it will be become eternal. So I supposed if exists some library to help me drawing them?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried drawing them? Did you experience a problem that we can help you solve?

Comment: My drawing experience is low, I started drawing the first problem but takes much time. That was the moment where I thought if there's an easy way to do this. My first though tell is about work with 2 and 3 array dimension operations

Comment: Do you need to generate the images programmatically? Do you need to rotate or scale the drawings in perspective or 3D? If not, it will be much easier to display scanned images from your illustrations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The ability to draw 3D shapes (such as cubes) and render them from different angles is built right into WPF. From the look of your cubes, you're going to want an [orthographic camera](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.media3d.orthographiccamera.aspx), rather than a perspective camera, because the lines composing your cubes are parallel.

You might also find the [Petzold.Media3D library](http://www.charlespetzold.com/blog/2007/08/110255.html) helpful, because it has objects like cubes built in (you don't have to write your own algorithms to build them).

Finally, you might [this primer](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/23332/WPF-3D-Primer) helpful in getting started with WPF 3D.

Once you have some idea of how to use 3D, it will just be a matter of putting cubes in your scene at the proper locations and positioning the cameras properly for viewing the cubes. You will probably want to keep reusing the same four camera positions: one for the "3D view", and one each for the top, side, and front views.

This should be a lot less work than trying to draw the cubes using 2D.